# Why do I get a Call to undefined method error?

Tags: php, class, methods, authentication, static

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   User::selectUser() in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\logic\login.php:13 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\logic\login.php on
>   line 13

I am 100% sure I checked everything that could cause this error, but still couldn't find it.

Here is my user class:

```
<?php

class User
{

    public $_gebruikersnaam;
    public $_wachtwoord;
    public $_voornaam;
    public $_tussenvoegsel;
    public $_achternaam;


//Koppeling tussen POJO-velden en databasevelden
    private static $DatabaseMapping =
        [
            //POJO-Veldnaam => Database-Veldnaam

            "gebruikersnaam" => "gebruikersnaam",
            "wachtwoord"     => "wachtwoord",
            "voornaam"       => "voornaam",
            "tussenvoegsel"  => "tussenvoegsel",
            "achternaam"     => "achternaam",
        ];

    public static function leesUitDatabase($rij)
    {
        $user = new User;
        foreach (self::$DatabaseMapping as $field => $kolom) {

            $user->$field = $rij[$kolom];

        }

        return $user;
    }


    public function save($dbh)
    {
        $dbh->insert('user', self::$DatabaseMapping, $this, true);
    }

    public static function selectUser($dbh, $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord)
    {
        try {

            $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE gebruikersnaam = :gebruikersnaam AND wachtwoord = :wachtwoord", ["gebruikersnaam" => $gebruikersnaam, "wachtwoord" => $wachtwoord]);

            return $stmt->fetchAll()[0];

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my login.php-class:

```
<?php
require_once("../config/dbhandler.php");
require_once("../classes/user.php");

//dbhandler-object maken
$dbh = new DBHandler();

//Ophalen login-gegevens
$gebruikersnaam = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
$wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];

//rij in de db ophalen waar de user zich bevindt
$rij = User::selectUser($dbh,$gebruikersnaam,$wachtwoord);

//Rij meesturen en user-object ervan maken
$user = User::leesUitDatabase($rij);


print_r($user);
?>
```

Somehow this line returns the error:

```
$rij = User::selectUser($dbh,$gebruikersnaam,$wachtwoord);
```

Help with the problem would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Ramon

Comment: No idea, looks correct to me. I just have two remarks. 1) You should use `password_hash` to check your passwords. Never store the clear passwords themselves in the database. 2) You can ommit the closing `?>`.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks :) I just don't understand why I have an error unfortunately, everything seems fine to me aswell

Comment: what is the value in `$rij`?

Comment: $rij has no value since it is a fatal error

Comment: maybe change `class User` to `public class User` ? But I am just guessing here...

Comment: I can't change it to public class User, PHP will say it expected end of file here

Comment: Please check your db connection and `selectUser()` function. comment `leesUitDatabase()` function for testing

Comment: are you sure this path: require_once("../classes/user.php");  is correct??

Comment: your "100% sure" statement is making me more curious, haha :) 
Because without any mistake an error can never happen, so there is something wrong for sure,
well can you please provide us your complete code, i mean all the files as a zip?

Comment: I found the solution it has to do with my require_once  and the relative path I am using. Absolute path works fine, but I don't want to use those, so probably my / should be changed to \

Comment: @AmrinderSingh you're right, the compiler is always 100% right and I am not, but this confused me so much. Anyways I would have found the error easier if the message displayed that something was wrong in my path but oh well.

Comment: @Ramon Brokking, you can use the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to always get the correct one for your platform. Although I always thought that Windows could handle slashes as well.